# How can I plot int64 values in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, int64

I am trying to plot a set of int64 numbers in Matlab R2013a.

As an example of what I am trying to achieve is shown below:

```
array_of_longs = [13286492335502040542 13286492335502040923 13286492335502042285 13286492335502042469 13286492335502042826 13286492335502044792 13286492335502045012 13286492335502046097 13286492335502047200 13286492335502049511 13286492335502050256 13286492335502050559 13286492335502053284 13286492335502055890 13286492335502056026 13286492335502057640];
horizontal_axis = 1:16;
f = figure;
plot(horizontal_axis,array_of_longs,'x')
```

Unfortunately, all of the x's in the plot appear to be in a straight horizonal line even though the values are different.
I have not been able to "zoom in" the y-axis to help show the variation.

Is there a trick or work around to plotting 64 bit integers?

Also, due to budget constraints I am not able to access toolboxes.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: FYI, those aren't `int64` values – they're doubles. Because they're greater than `flintmax` they may not be represented exactly. You need to use `int64` or `uint64` to represent 64-bit integers. As far as plotting goes, how about subtracting the `min` value and plotting that? Or you can use `ylim` or `axis` to adjust your axis values.

Comment: @horchler - Thanks for pointing out the correction. I tried subtracting the min as per your suggestion, however, unfortunately the difference in some cases is also a `int64` or `double`!

Comment: What @horchler suggested works fine, just define your array as `uint64(..)`, and plot `array_of_longs-min(array_of_longs)`.

Comment: Interesting, it seems as an array of `uint64` is not exact for all 64 bits. This does not give expected output in case one expect it to be the same number, `p=uint64([0;0]); p(1)=13286492335502040542`. However `q = uint64(13286492335502040542)` does. It is also working with `p=uint64([0;0]); p(1)=uint64(13286492335502040542)`. I think it is kind of weird. Maybe anyone knows more? Matlab 2014a, windows 7.

Comment: @patrick, linking in your question ;):  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591588/uint64-is-not-exact-for-vectors-in-matlab

Comment: @ItamarKatz I tried exactly that but in my dataset the `(max - min)` also ends up being a uint64 so I still end up with a plot where I cannot distinguish which yvalue a 'x' corresponds to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a workaround which works for now. I have taken the length of the `uint64` array and assigned a random int to each unique `uint64` value. Then I have plotted the random values against the `x-values`.
E.g.

```
% array_of_longs = {large set of uint64 values}
unique_longs = unique(array_of_longs);
num_unique = length(unique_longs);
random_key = randi([1,num_unique*2],1,num_unique);
array_keys = ones(1,length(array_of_longs));
for i=1:length(array_of_longs)
    array_keys(i) = random_key(find(unique_longs == array_of_longs(i)));
end

f = figure;
plot(x_values,array_keys,'x');
```

I will also output a table that maps each `uint64` value to its key.
Thanks for all your comments.