# uint64 is not exact for vectors in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have discovered an inconsistency for `uint64` when using vectors in Matlab. It seems as an array of uint64 is not exact for all 64 bits. This did not give the output I expected,

```
p=uint64([0;0]);
p(1)=13286492335502040542
p =
 13286492335502041088
                    0
```

However

```
q = uint64(13286492335502040542)
q =
 13286492335502040542
```

does. It is also working with

```
p(1)=uint64(13286492335502040542)
p =
 13286492335502040542
                    0
```

Working with unsigned integers one expect a special behaviour and usually also perfect precision. This seems weird and even a bit uncanny. I do not see this problem with smaller numbers. Maybe anyone knows more? I do not expect this to be an unknown problem, so I guess there must be some explanation to it. I would be good to know why this happen and when, to be able to avoid it. As usual this kind of issues is mentioned nowhere in the documentation.

Matlab 2014a, windows 7.

**EDIT**

It is worth mentioning that I can see the same behaviour when defining arrays directly.

```
p=uint64([13286492335502040542;13286492335502040543])
p =
 13286492335502041088
 13286492335502041088
```

This is the root to why I ask this question. I have hard to see workaround for this case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While it might be surprising, this is a floating point precision issue. :-)

The thing is, all numeric literals are by default of type `double` in MATLAB; that's why:

```
13286492335502040542 == 13286492335502041088
```

will return `true`; the floating point representation in double precision of `13286492335502040542` is `13286492335502041088`. Since `p` has the class `uint64`, all assignments done to it will cast the right-hand-side to its class.

On another hand, the `uint64(13286492335502040542)` "call" will be optimized by the MATLAB interpreter to avoid the overhead of calling the `uint64` function for the `double` argument, and will convert the literal directly to its unsigned integer representation (which is exact).

On a third hand [sic], the function call optimization doesn't apply to

```
p = uint64([13286492335502040542;13286492335502040543])
```

because the argument of `uint64` is not a literal, but the result of an expression, i.e. the result of the `vertcat` operator applied to two `double` operands. In this case the MATLAB interpreter is not smart enough to figure out that the two function calls should "commute" (concatenation of uint should be the same as uint of concatenation), so it evaluates the concatenation (which gives an array of equal `double` because FP precision), then converts the two similar `double` values to `uint64`.

**TLDR:** the difference between

```
p = uint64(13286492335502040542);
```

and

```
u = 13286492335502040542; p = uint64(u);
```

is a side effect of function call optimization.

Answer (score 7):

Matlab, unless told otherwise reads numbers as double, then casts to the relevant datatype. The Matlab [double](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html) datatype allows for 51 bits for the floating point fraction, giving the possibility to store 52 bit integers without loss of prepossession (mantissa). Notice that `13286492335502041088` is just `13286492335502040543` with the last 12 bits set to zero.

the solution as you said, is to convert the literals directly `uint64(13286492335502040543)`.

`p=uint64([13286492335502040542;13286492335502040543])` does not work because it creates a double array and then converts it to uint64

This issue is mentioned in the [uint64](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uint64.html) documentation, under 'More About', although it doesn't mention that laterals are read as doubles unless otherwise specified.

Comment: I understand, for some reason I thought matlabs JIT compiler was smarter than this (like understanding that I want an array of `uint64`). I guess that matlab does not really handle `uint64` then. The options of downcasting from double (which IMO is ugly), or adding values one-by-one is definitely not sufficient :(. Do you know any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Matlab supports uint64 just fine, you generally don't add data hard coded as literals in your code, if you read from a file, there are ways to read directly into uint64.

Answer (score 0):

I agree this seems weird and I don't have an explanation. I do have a workaround:

```
p=[uint64(13286492335502040542);uint64(13286492335502040543)]
```

i.e., cast the separate values to `uint64`s.

Comment: Well, that is true, but this is typically something which must be done by hand. Thus it cannot be seen as a proper workaround in my eyes. Thanks anyway.

Comment: If you are typing in the numbers by hand, it doesn't seem a stretch to add the uint64(...), for any other method of data input there are other ways...